# Hot reload with Spring MVC in VSCode?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, visual-studio-code

Does anyone know of a way to hot reload a Spring MVC (not spring boot) application in VSCode? I'm using the *Microsoft Java Extension* Pack and *Tomcat for Java* extensions to compile and run them, but it seems that for every change I make I need to rebuild the `.war`file and restart my server.

Personally, I think this is highly inefficient and tiresome. Does anyone know how to make this process automatic? I migrated from Intellij because apparently this isn't possible in the community version.

P.S.: To be more clear, I'm using Spring MVC but I intend to build a REST API with it, so I will not be using any `.jsp` files.

Answer (score 0):

There's a feature request in github: [Autorebuild option as eclipse](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-maven/issues/752), where the author ask the auto-rebuild feature including rebuild war packages.

The programmer still keeps the issue open and waits for users to vote it up then decides if this feature is needed, so you may upvote and comment there.